# Why the following arrow function won't execute but a simple if statement will?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, arrow-functions

Is there a problem with code? or do i lack the understanding of how to fire functions without specifically calling them?

code:

```
let age = prompt('How old are you?');

//Arrow function that won't execute:

()=> { return (age < 18 ? alert('You are too young!') : alert('welcome!')); };

//This executes just fine:

if (age <= 18) {
    alert('You are to young!');
} else { 
    alert('welcome!');
};
```

Comment: You just define what would happen if you execute the function, you never actually call it.

Comment: Functions have to be called in order them being executed. An IIFE might help: `(() => {...})();`. Althought it's not clear where you want to use the return value of that function.

Comment: "*do i lack the understanding of how to fire functions without specifically calling them?*" you *could* cause a function to be executed without explicitly calling it with `()`. However, is there really a need for this here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript functions can be variables themselves. What your code has so far done is created a function but not actually assigned it to a variable. So you're saying "Here is a function to run" but never actually saving that function anywhere. There's a few methods you can do here.

1. Just keep the code as an if statement
2. Assign the function to a variable and call it like this:

```
var checkAge = ()=> { return (age < 18 ? alert('You are too young!') : alert('welcome!')); };
```

And then call it with `checkAge()`.

What you really should do instead though is pass age as a parameter into the checkAge function like this:

```
var checkAge = (a)=> { return (a < 18 ? alert('You are too young!') : alert('welcome!')); };
checkAge(a);
```

Because this means you could then use that function again somewhere else in your code whenever you like.

Comment: For what purpose are you returning `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```js
const checkAge = (question = 'How old are you?') => {
  let age = Number(prompt(question));
  if (!isNaN(age)) {
    alert(age <= 18 ? 'You are too young!' : 'welcome!');
    return age;
  } else {
    checkAge('Please enter a number!\nHow old are you?');
  }
}

// call the function
checkAge();
```